# Why does my Spring Boot POST output a "Whitelabel Error Page"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post

so I'm trying to POST some kind of "Log in" window where the user has to write their full name to log in. But I got a "Whitelabel Error Page" instead. Below you can find my code. Would appreciate ur help

First my "User" class  ("vorname" = first name & "nachname" = surname):

```
package POST;

public class User {
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;

    public User(String vorname, String nachname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }
}
```

Here is my "UserData" class:

```
package POST;

import java.util.List;

public class UserData {

    private List<User> blogs;

    public User createBlog(String vorname, String nachname) {
        User newBlog = new User(vorname, nachname);
        blogs.add(newBlog);
        return newBlog;
    }

    private static UserData instance = null;
    public static UserData getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new UserData();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

My "UserAPI" class ("vorname" = first name & "nachname" = surname):

```
package POST;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import java.util.Map;

public class UserAPI {
    UserData userData = UserData.getInstance();

    @PostMapping(value = "/createUser", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> user) {
        String vorname = user.get("vorname");
        String nachname = user.get("nachname");
        return userData.createBlog(vorname, nachname);
    }
}
```

and my "POSTApplication" class:

```
package POST;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class POSTApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(POSTApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the output on my localhost:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>     This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
>     this as a fallback.
>     Tue Dec 24 15:30:49 CET 2019
>     There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>     No message available

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `404 Http Status Code` denotes that the resource you are trying to access is not found in the server.

So, I think you forget to add `@RestController` annotation on the top of your `UserAPI` class, which is why the resource is not found.

Try this:

```
@RestController
public class UserAPI {
UserData userData = UserData.getInstance();

@PostMapping(value = "/createUser", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public User createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> user) {
    String vorname = user.get("vorname");
    String nachname = user.get("nachname");
    return userData.createBlog(vorname, nachname);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, now i got an "status": 415, "error": "Unsupported Media Type",

Comment: Remove the consumes/produces from the mapping, these do not have any effect. and make sure your request path is correct. 415 indicates that this mapping does not exist. It should be POST localhost:8080/createUser.

Comment: 415 indicates that the data you are sending is not in an acceptable form. I edited the code. You can accept User as a requestbody instead.

Comment: If your controller is saying that it consumes application/json, then your request needs a Content-Type header of application/json ...

Comment: I sent the data like this: {"vorname":"test","nachname":"test2"} and the Content-Type header is json. But now i got an Status: 500  "Internal Server Error". Why should i write return userData.createBlog(vorname, nachname);
there is no declaration of those two.

Comment: Kindly refrain from asking more questions. Your original question was regarding `404` and it's resolved. For further questions, post a new one. It's a bad practice to continue them over comments.

Comment: You are getting Null pointer exception, I guess.  Inside your UserData class initialize blogs list. Like: private List<User> blogs= new ArrayList<>();

Comment: NVM got it. the "blogs.add(newBlog);" was the Problem. THANKS